# Python: compare and find matches in a list of tuples and a nested list

Tags: python, list, compare

I need to compare items from a list of tuples with items from a nested list and return a list with items from the tuple and the nested list.

Input data:

```
data1 = [('Name1', {'code':['12345']}),
         ('Name2', {'code':['78901']})]

data2 = [['12345', '123456', 'name1'],
         ['78901', '789012', 'name2'],
         ['34567', '345678', 'name3']]
```

I have no issues in converting the input data1 to match the nested list format of data2 if that makes things easier.

What I need is something like:

```
data3 = [['Name1', '123456', 'name1']
         ['Name2', '789012', 'name2']]
```

Basically comparing `data1[x][1]['code'][0] to data2[x][0]`

What I have so far and but I'm not sure if it's right:

```
data3 = []
for i in range(len(data2)):
    if data1[i][1]['code'][0] in [data2][i][0]:
       data3.append([data1[i][0], data2[i][1], data2[i][2]])
```

This returns an **IndexError: list index out of range**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data2 list is longer than data1 and you iterate data1 with length of data2, with more indexes than it has. There was an error `[data2]` enclosed in brackets in if statement.

Fixed original code:

```
data3 = []
for i in range(len(data1)):
    for j in range(len(data2)):
        if data1[i][1]['code'][0] in data2[j][0]:
            data3.append([data1[i][0], data2[j][1], data2[j][2]])
```

Simplified by iterating directly over lists:

```
data3 = []
for i in data1:
    for j in data2:
        if i[1]['code'][0] in j[0]:
            data3.append([i[0], j[1], j[2]])
```

Comment: The simplified version was easier to understand and works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Create an inverse mapping of `data1` first:

```
inverse_data1 = {v['code'][0]: k for k, v in data1}
```

Now the rest is much simpler; you can look codes against that inverse mapping and find the corresponding name in O(1) time:

```
data3 = [[inverse_data1[d[0]]] + d[1:] for d in data2 if d[0] in inverse_data1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> inverse_data1 = {v['code'][0]: k for k, v in data1}
>>> [[inverse_data1[d[0]]] + d[1:] for d in data2 if d[0] in inverse_data1]
[['Name1', '123456', 'name1'], ['Name2', '789012', 'name2']]
```

Generally speaking, do not loop over `range(len(somelist))` when you can just loop *directly* over that list. You can use the `enumerate()` function to add an index if you need one for other purposes. Your `data1` and `data2` lists are not of equal length, so you cannot just use indices that work in one on the other.

Your approach would require *nested* loops (very inefficient, you are now looping over the whole of `data2` for every entry in `data1`):

```
data3 = []
for d1 in data1:
    for d2 in data2:
        if d1[1]['code'][0] == d2[0]:
            data3.append(d1[0] + d2[1:])
```